# Using a required attribute on input (type file) causes the input to stop working on iPhone ios 11

Tags: html, ios11, input-type-file

I have a form that is used to upload an image.  The input (type file) has a required attribute, so selecting submit before selecting a file causes a validation error.  When using an iPhone with ios 11 (I have tested with chrome, firefox, and safari), if you first select submit in order to receive the validation error (which on an iPhone ios 11 is "Select a file") and then select "Choose File" while the "Select a file" is still displayed (meaning that to reproduce the problem, you cannot first select somewhere else on the screen to remove the "Select a file" validation error), the popup to allow you to select a file does not appear.  From this point on, even when refreshing the page, "Choose file" will not do anything.  Closing the browser (by double clicking the home button and swiping up on the browser), then reopening the browser will allow the input to work again (till you follow the instructions above to reproduce the problem).  I discovered that if I remove the meta tag with the content attribute in the code below, the problem does not occur.

Here is the code (just a basic form).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input required type="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Add File" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any thoughts on why this is occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a mobile Safari bug.
I minimized the possibility of someone clicking the input while the validation message is showing by blurring the focus of the active element a half second later.

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');
var button = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');
button.onclick = function (e) {
  if (!form.checkValidity()) {
    setTimeout(function () {       
      document.activeElement.blur();
    }, 500);
  }
};
```